# sequence of real numbers in an array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have several arrays as follows:

```
$number1 = array('A', 0.42);
$number2 = array('B', 0.44);
$number3 = array('C', 0.41);
$number4 = array('D', 0.43);
```

I want to display the results like this:

```
0.41
0.42
0.43
0.44
```

how to display the results like that? thanks :)

Comment: Why the downvotes? Seems like a legit question.

Comment: Probably because he seemed to have not tried anything.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Well.. it took me a while to figure this one out too ;)

Comment: @DainisAbols I'm not saying this is easy to do, just that the OP seems to have tried nothing, while here on stackoverflow it's required to show what you have already tried and then build up from that.

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
echo $number3[1], "\n";
echo $number1[1], "\n";
echo $number4[1], "\n";
echo $number2[1], "\n";
```

You will get

```
0.41
0.42
0.43
0.44
```

But if you want to learn something about sorting you should [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

Comment: Really ?? Try that for 1000 array list

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using data and array is wrong. What if tomorrow you have 500 more numbers to sort ?

You should have one array that contain all your values.

```
<?
$data = array(
  "A" => 0.45,
  "B" => 0.43,
  "C" => 0.41,
  "D" => 0.42
);

asort($data);
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```

should print something like

```
C = 0.41
D = 0.42
B = 0.43
A = 0.45
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would condense that code into one array, which would allow a nice for / foreach loop, and sorting:

```
$numbers = array(
    'A' => 0.42,
    'B' => 0.44,
    'C' => 0.41,
    'D' => 0.43
);

asort($numbers);

foreach ($numbers as $number)
{
    echo $number . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You **don't** need to remake your arrays. You can use the double `$$`. This will print not the variable, but will try to access a variable that is stored in the value.

Like this:

```
$number1 = array('A', 0.42);
$number2 = array('B', 0.44);
$number3 = array('C', 0.41);
$number4 = array('D', 0.43);

$k = 1;
$name = 'number' . $k;
while ( isset($$name) )
{
    $tmp = $$name;
    echo $tmp[1] . '<br/>';
    $k++;
    $name = 'number' . $k;
}
```